# Converting DateTime a specific format

Tags: java, json, datetime

I have an endpoint in which is takes the following json as it's request body:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-10-10 21:46:07"}
```

I convert this timestamp string into an Instant by performing the following:

```
   private Instant formatTimestamp(String timestamp)
   {
      final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                                             .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                             .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

      return Instant.from(formatter.parse(timestamp));

   }
```

I then call an external API and send them a string version of my Instant object (by calling the `.toString()` method on the Instant object).

However I have noticed that the format the external API accepts and what I send are a bit different.
This is what the external API accepts:
`2021-10-10T12:34:56.000Z`
and this is what I send: `2021-10-10T11:34:56Z`. As you can see I am missing the trailing 000 from the date.

Is there any way of formatting the instant object to conform to the external API format?

Comment: Hi, the API I am calling takes in a string like this: 2021-10-10T12:34:56.000Z.
My endpoint accepts a string in like the following format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: @tcho1506996 ... but your API doesn't return a string, it returns an Instant which __does not have a format__. You can't turn an Instant into a string without telling the instant what it should look like. Your code doesn't include the bit where that happens. Hence, no way to help you out here without that info.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I have edited the whole question so hopefully it should be easier to understand

Comment: Does the external system reject your text without the fractional second? Your text is perfectly acceptable under the ISO 8601 standard, and acceptable to common sense.

Comment: You have a method name that is lying. It's called 'formatTimestamp' but it does the reverse: It __parses__ a timestamp. As I keep saying: An Instant doesn't have a format. Somewhere in your code, maybe in a library, somebody somewhere either runs `instant.toString()`, or `someDateTimeFormatter.format(yourInstant)` - and then puts the string this gets you onto the wire. __THAT CODE__ needs to be changed; it isn't in your paste, thus, no way to answer your question.

Comment: Also note that `2021-10-10 21:46:07` is not a representation of a certain instantaneous point on the time-line, as it is missing timezone information.

Answer (score 1):

My taste would be for this formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter INSTANT_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Demonstration:

```
    Instant parsedInstant = formatTimestamp("2021-10-10 21:46:07");
    String formattedTimestamp = INSTANT_FORMATTER.format(parsedInstant);
    System.out.println(formattedTimestamp);
```

Output in my time zone was:

> 2021-10-10T19:46:07.000Z

The `.SSS` in the format pattern string that I am using specifyes exactly three decimals on the seconds. I am also specifying that the formatter must always use UTC (`ZoneOffset.UTC`) because your service expects a trailing `Z` for UTC. My formatter may be a bit wordy because I wanted to reuse the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`. If you prefer it shorter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter INSTANT_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ROOT)
                .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

It gives the same result as before.